# swift3 webview with post request

Tags: swift3

I am running a school project and I am new from swift3.

By searching, I know how to pass a data from one view to anther:
[Passing data from a tableview to webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40288974/passing-data-from-a-tableview-to-webview)

In the post above, he is using http get request to pass data to website, then reload the webivew:

```
let URL = NSURL(string: "https://www.example.com?data=\(passData)")
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: URL! as URL) as URLRequest)
```

I see some useful links like about code with http post request in here:
[HTTP Request in Swift with POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364914/http-request-in-swift-with-post-method). In a result, the code can print out the http response.

My question is that, how to implement a webview with sending a http post reuqest, like id, name, etc, instead of get method.

In anther words: I want to reload the webview(like example.com) and that website will contain the value I sent via http post request.

example.com:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just create a `URLRequest` for POST as shown in the second link, and pass it to the `webView`:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.example.com/")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let postString = "id=\(idString)"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
webView.loadRequest(request) //if your `webView` is `UIWebView`
```

(Consider using `WKWebView` rather than `UIWebView`.)

You may need `idString` to be escaped if it contains some special characters.

---

By the way, the two line code:

```
let URL = NSURL(string: "https://www.example.com?data=\(passData)")
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: URL! as URL) as URLRequest)
```

does not seem to be a good Swift 3 code. It can be written as:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com?data=\(passData)")!
webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
```

Comment: There's another solution if the above doesn't work:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44951545/4260691